# HTML parsing to get all text data with delimiters after all HTML tags using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I haven html content as below

```
<h3>Features</h3>
<ul id="features"> 
  <li>Light weight fabric with fast Wicking technology for quick drying even during heavy sweating.</li>
  <li>Flat Seams on complete garment to prevent chafing.</li>
  <li>Reflectors on Tshirt for the safety during Dim-Light runs.</li> 
  <li>Raglan sleeves for better stretchability</li>
</ul>\n  Bring out the confidence in you with comfort by Adding NIVIA\'s Sports Tee with Unique combination of subtle design & features of Stretchable light fabric with quick dry technology.
```

I am trying to extract the text from above html content. 
If i use `BeautifulSoup(html_content).get_text()` it does not add symantic seperation for different `html` tags. The result is as below

> FeaturesLight weight fabric with fast Wicking technology for quick
>   drying even during heavy sweating.Flat Seams on complete garment to
>   prevent chafing.Reflectors on Tshirt for the safety during Dim-Light
>   runs.Raglan sleeves for better stretchabilityBring out the confidence
>   in you with comfort by Adding NIVIA's Sports Tee with Unique
>   combination of subtle design & features of Stretchable light fabric
>   with quick dry technology.

If you look at the **first word(FeaturesLight)**, which was expected to be **seperated by space** is not done here.

Now, I tried get the text under different `html` tags so that the above issue doesnt happen by using `find_all()`

```
for span in BeautifulSoup(html_content).find_all('ul'):
       print(span.text)
```

Gives me most of the text, but the last part in the html content which is to tagged to any html tag is not extracted.

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the separator parameter of the get_text method:

`BeautifulSoup(html_content).get_text(separator = " ")`

instead of

`BeautifulSoup(html_content).get_text()`

This will add the delimiter as specified in seperator.

Example below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<h3>Features</h3><ul id="features"><li>Light weight fabric with fast Wicking technology for quick drying even during heavy sweating.</li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.get_text()
# Output
#'FeaturesLight weight fabric with fast Wicking technology for quick drying even during heavy sweating.'
soup.get_text(separator=' ')
#Output
# 'Features Light weight fabric with fast Wicking technology for quick drying even during heavy sweating.'
soup.get_text(separator='/ ')
#Output
#'Features/ Light weight fabric with fast Wicking technology for quick drying even during heavy sweating.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `findAll(text=True)`

```
html='''<h3>Features</h3><ul id="features"><li>Light weight fabric with fast Wicking technology for quick drying even during heavy sweating.</li><li>Flat Seams on complete garment to prevent chafing.</li><li>Reflectors on Tshirt for the safety during Dim-Light runs.</li><li>Raglan sleeves for better stretchability</li></ul>\n  Bring out the confidence in you with comfort by Adding NIVIA\'s Sports Tee with Unique combination of subtle design & features of Stretchable light fabric with quick dry technology. '''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(' '.join(soup.findAll(text=True)))
```

Comment: Thank you. This served my purpose